# KeyError when using Translate() in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to remove the whitespace in a data that I need to insert into a column.

```
Error Message
x = self._index[x]
KeyError: 'snumber'
```

Code:

```
cur_t = conn_t.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur_t.execute("""
                    SELECT TRANSLATE(snumber, ' ', ''), age
                    FROM sprofile """)

    for row in cur_t:
                    print row['snumber']
```

The code works if I will use `print row[0]` instead of the column name.
If I run `SELECT TRANSLATE(snumber, ' ', '' FROM sprofile` in psql, the code works fine.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: If i run the code `for row in cur_t:
                    print row['snumber']` it gives me `Error Message
x = self._index[x]
KeyError: 'snumber'`

Comment: What is `snumber`? It seems like there is more relevant code that should be posted.

Comment: `snumber` is studentnumber. Some of them contains whitespace at the beginning that's why I want to get rid of the whitespace. I'm just printing it here to see if it will work.

Comment: Aha. Please post the table code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that since I used a function on my data, the column name that will be used will be the function name. `(e.g. row['translate'])` but I can still use the 'snumber' column name by making an "alias" to it `(e.g. SELECT TRANSLATE(snumber, ' ', '') as snumber`

Comment: Yep, this is exactly right. You can accept your own answer :)